# Creating launchable tmux configurations?

Tags: tmux

I find myself often doing the same thing with `tmux`:

1. `cd` to a given directory.
2. `tmux`
3. Rename window to what I'm doing.
4. Split the window vertically 50%.
5. Start one process in the left window.
6. Start another process in the right window.
7. Profit.

Is there a way for me to automate launching all of this so that I can run a single command and get the window I'm looking for?

Comment: What about a shell alias?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Archwiki saves the day! [Session Initialization](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux#Session_initialization) on the tmux page gives an example.

That said, instead of starting tmux as `tmux`, `tmux new -s name` will name the session when it starts instead of giving it a number.

## Session initialization

---

You can have tmux open a session with preloaded windows by including those details in your ~/.tmux.conf:

```
new  -n WindowName Command
neww -n WindowName Command
neww -n WindowName Command
```

To start a session with split windows (multiple panes), include the splitw command below the neww you would like to split; thus:

```
new  -s SessionName -n WindowName Command
neww -n foo/bar foo
splitw -v -p 50 -t 0 bar
selectw -t 1 
selectp -t 0
```

would open 2 windows, the second of which would be named foo/bar and would be split vertically in half (50%) with foo running above bar. Focus would be in window 2 (foo/bar), top pane (foo).

> Note: Numbering for sessions, windows and panes starts at zero, unless
>   you have specified a base-index of 1 in your .conf

To manage multiple sessions, source separate session files from your conf file:

```
# initialize sessions
bind F source-file ~/.tmux/foo
bind B source-file ~/.tmux/bar
```

Answer (score 6):

Rob's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61391/8431) is great and explains exactly how to handle sessions from within tmux itself. Now, if you don't mind using a third-party tool, [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator) is a great project that helps *create and manage sessions easily*.

Each session is controlled by a config file that allows you to define all of your windows and panes along with their layouts and default commands to run within them. It also allows you to define a default project directory, specific socket, and daemons that are required to be running (e.g. mysql). To top it off, it provides an easy method to attach to them as well: simply run `mux [session-name]` and it will either start the session or attach to it if it is already running. I've been using it for a little while now and love it (thanks [aziz](https://github.com/aziz)!).

https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator