# How do I run a shell command from .tmux.conf

Tags: shell, tmux

How do I run a shell command from `.tmux.conf`, or otherwise automatically when tmux launches, without having to hit any other command?

How can I create an alias, a function, or a script which boils down to, for example

tmuxirc -> tmux + irssi

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61386/creating-launchable-tmux-configurations

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want to externally invoke tmux from your shell rather than doing this from within tmux, so `.tmux.conf` is the wrong place. You can use a shell alias (place this in your `.bashrc` for reuse):

```
alias tmuxirc='tmux new-session -s irc irssi'
```

Comment: I use zsh, but otherwise 100% correct.

Comment: here when the process is ended it end tmux as well, is it possible to keep tmux-session alive?

Answer (score 22):

While it doesn't seem to be what you were looking for, the solution to:

> How do I run a shell command from .tmux.conf

is `run-shell`, or, in its abbreviated form, `run`. From the `tmux` man page:

> ```
> run-shell shell-command
>                (alias: run)
>          Execute shell-command in the background without creating a win-
>          dow.  After it finishes, any output to stdout is displayed in
>          copy mode.  If the command doesn't return success, the exit sta-
>          tus is also displayed.
> ```

If you need to silently kick off a script in the background whenever you launch `tmux`, you could use `run "command > /dev/null"`.

Answer (score 7):

I do something similar with a script. When I want to fire up tmux with my development configuration I call it.  The script itself looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux has-session -t development
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    tmux new-session -s development -n editor -d
    tmux send-keys -t development 'cd /var/www/htdocs/' C-m
    tmux send-keys -t development 'vim' C-m
    tmux split-window -v -t development
    tmux split-window -v -t development
    tmux select-layout -t development main-horizontal
    tmux send-keys -t development:0.1 'cd /var/www/htdocs/' C-m
    tmux new-window -n console -t development
    tmux send-keys -t development:1 'cd /var/www/htdocs/' C-m
    tmux select-window -t development:0
fi
tmux attach -t development
```

What this gives me is a tmux session with 2 windows, window 1 has a Vim session in the top of the screen, with two terminals in the bottom 3rd or so of the screen, all pointed at my /var/www/htdocs/ directory.  Window 2 is just a full screen console.  Good thing about this is that it won't recreate the session if it's already there, it will just attach to it.

Comment: You might want to look at [tmuxinator](https://github.com/aziz/tmuxinator).

Comment: how do you execute this script from conf?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `display-message` command in `tmux`, from its man page:

> > display-message [-p] [-c target-client] [-t target-pane] [message]
> >
> > (alias: display)
> >
> > Display a message.  If -p is given, the output is printed to stdout, otherwise it is displayed in the target-client status line.  The format of message is described in the FORMATS section; information is taken from target-pane if -t is given, otherwise the active pane for the session attached to target-client.

And in FORMATS section, there is a variable named `session_name`, it will be replaced with the name of the session if you use it in format `#{session_name}`.

Try to run `tmux display-message -p '#{session_name}'` when you are in a tmux session. Maybe you will see a number, it is the id of the session you attached. Run `tmux ls` to check the session list.

However, when you start up a tmux by `tmux new -s myproject`, you will see `myproject` as the output, but not a number. Because you specified the name of the session when you start tmux.

So, my solution is to put a piece of code in `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# [tmux] load scripts in ~/.tmux on creating a new pane
# load order: __before__.sh, ${session_name}.sh, __after__.sh
function tmux_load_startup_scripts_by_session_name() {  
  if [[ -n ${TMUX} ]]; then
    local env_before_script="${HOME}/.tmux/__before__.sh"
    [[ -f "${env_before_script}" ]] && { . "${env_before_script}"; }
    local env_main_script="${HOME}/.tmux/$(tmux display-message -p '#{session_name}').sh"
    [[ -f "${env_main_script}" ]] && { . "${env_main_script}"; }
    local env_after_script="${HOME}/.tmux/__after__.sh"
    [[ -f "${env_after_script}" ]] && { . "${env_after_script}"; }
  fi
}
tmux_load_startup_scripts_by_session_name
```

### Usage

```
mkdir ~/.tmux
cat "__before__.sh" > ~/.tmux/__before__.sh
cat "__after__.sh" > ~/.tmux/__after__.sh
cat "sample.sh" > ~/.tmux/sample.sh
tmux new -s sample
```

You will see output on each panel you create:

```
__before__.sh
sample.sh
__after__.sh
```

The advantage of this solution is you can specify different scripts for different projects or environment.